# Script: echoing lines from one file to another doesn't print '\t'. Issue

Tags: bash

I need to create a file by modifying some lines of a source one.
I developed a loop `'while read line; do'`. Inside it, the lines I read and don't modify go just:

```
echo -e "$line" >> "xxxx.c"
```

My issue is that some of that lines start with '\t', and they won't print the output file.

**Example:**

```
while read line;   
do                                                             
if echo "$line" | grep -q 'timeval TIMEOUT = {25,0};'                    
then
  echo "$line"
fi
```

Any help? I've tried with the `printf` command also but without success.

Comment: use `while IFS= read -r line` to preserve whitespace and escapes.

Comment: Thank you a lot! that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you could just remove "-e" argument from the echo command.

From echo man page:

```
-e enable interpretation of backslash escapes
```

Comment: That's not the problem.